# What about OverflowQuestions.com?

Tags: discussion

I was just googling some programming questions when I came across OverflowQuestions.com, which seems to mirror StackOverflow's content.

What to do about it?

Comment: It comes close to meeting the [attribution requirements](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), but doesn't quite do so. I can't find where it links back to the original question, and the author name doesn't link to their user profile. (It is also *glacially* slow, but I guess that doesn't matter.)

Comment: @CodyGray yes, it is glacially slow. I was surprised to see this because it didn't even contain the answers from the original question.

Comment: Perhaps they arrive with a delay, I do see answers in there. And when I turned off the ad blocker, a whole lot of ads.